# Is INT_MIN * -1 a no-op on x86?

Tags: x86, undefined-behavior, signed, integer-overflow

Signed integers are represented on x86 via two's complement, where the sign bit has the value `-(2^N)`. This results in a typical representable value range between `-2^N` and `2^N - 1` (e.g. `-32768` through `32767`).

I was curious what would occur if I took the minimum signed integer value on my system and multiply it by `-1` in an attempt to "force" a maximum value greater than the maximum representable value of signed integers on my system.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void){
    signed int x, y;

    x = INT_MIN;
    y = x * -1;

    printf("%d\n%d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
# gcc -std=c89 -pedantic int_min_test.c

# ./a.out
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

I was expecting an integer overflow (resulting in the typical value rollover), but it appears as if no operation took place regarding the multiplication of `x` with `-1`.

Is the multiplication of `INT_MIN` with `-1` a no-op in x86?

Comment: Wouldn't the rollover precisely produce the smallest possible value again?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour (for 2's complement) - nothing to do with x86 specifically.

Comment: What @KerrekSB said. If you want to observe this without UB, just used unsigned types.

Comment: It totally wrapped, it just wraps to the value you started with. That's no evidence of lack of overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using gcc 4.8.5, the line `y = x * -1;` is computed using the following instruction:

```
neg    %eax
```

The neg operation flips the bits of the word and then adds 1. For 32 bit 2's complement the result is:

```
0x80000000 # Start value
0x7FFFFFFF # Flip bits
0x80000000 # Add 1
```

As you see, the computer is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. This is not a no-op, as `neg` modifies the `AF`, `CF`, `OF`, `PF`, `SF`, and `ZF` flags. It is just an artifact of the binary representation being used. As others have stated it is simply undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

For C (based on the question's original tagging, and the example code being written in C), it's undefined behavior, so no, the result of the C expression `INT_MIN * -1` is not "a no-op", it's undefined behavior. In practice the result is likely to be observed inconsistently depending on how you observe it, possibly even temporally inconsistently. Don't do it.

If you want to ask about the x86 `imul` instruction, that's a different question and I believe (32-bit) `imul` of `0x80000000` by `0xffffffff` produces `0x80000000`. But that has nothing to do with what you should expect to see in C.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the x86 opcode behavior. I've removed the `C` tag now to help prevent the confusion.

Comment: Just changing the tagging doesn't really help when the code in the question is C. If you want to ask about asm then use asm sample code. C does not translate directly to asm.

Comment: That's a good point, with undefined behavior the C implementation could produce any opcode sequence. I'll rewrite a better question to focus correctly on the x86 behavior.

Comment: Yes, `imul` produces the full double-width result and truncates.  So you can check with something like `calc`: `0x80000000 * 0xffffffff` => `0x7fffffff80000000` (unsigned calculation, which is fine since we're only keeping the low half).  So yes, the low half is `0x80000000`, and that's the result you'll get from the two-operand or immediate form of imul.

Answer (score 2):

On an x86 processor, instructions that would multiply an "int" by -1 will,
when given the bit pattern 0x80000000 yield that same bit pattern as a result.
It is important to note, however, that C compilers for the x86 may be divided
into a number of categories:

1. On some compilers, all signed integer operations will behave as though math is performed using the native operations of the exact length, which is is equivalent to performing the operations with infinite precision and adding or subtracting to/from any out-of-range value whatever multiple of the integer modulus is necessary to bring it in range.  Such behavior is analogous to what happens with unsigned types except that the range is different.  On such compilers, `-INT_MIN == INT_MIN`.
2. On some compilers, all signed integer operations will behave as though performed with infinite precision, but may add or subtract to/from any out-of-range value any arbitrary multiple of the integer modulus, possibly yielding a result that behaves like a number outside the range of its type.  This allows an expression like "x+1>y" to be replaced with "x>=y", and may also allow code to be moved outside loops in ways that would not be possible if overflows had to wrap consistently.  On such compilers, `-INT_MIN` might equal `INT_MIN`, or might equal `-(long)INT_MIN`, or any other value whose lower 32 bits match INT_MIN.  Some such compilers will truncate out-of-range values when storing them to variables, but some may not.  A key feature of such compilers is that code need not prevent overflow if "extra" bits of the results will be irrelevant in cases where overflow occurs [e.g. `uint1=ushort1*ushort2;`].
3. Some compilers will use integer overflow as a basis for negating the laws of time and causality.  When using such compilers, one must include logic to prevent overflow at all costs whether or not the machine code generated thereby contributes anything toward the program's meeting requirements.

Personally, I think the second form of semantics makes the most sense; it
allows nearly all of the useful optimizations that would be possible under
the third, and makes it possible for programmers to enable optimizations
that would not be possible under the third.  If the behavioral guarantees under the second form would be sufficient to ensure that a program will meet its behavioral requirements even when overflows occur, forcing programmers to handle overflows anyway will make code less efficient.  While there will often be cases where overflow checking is a good idea even at the cost of reduced efficiency, I think there's something absurd about "optimizing" compilers mandating that programmers write less efficient code than would otherwise be needed.